# Why is my code not running the function correctly

Tags: c, arrays, function, loops, multidimensional-array

The code need to find the max element in the 2d array that has the distance less than <(square(d)).

The 2d array is sorted from the the least distance to the max distance.

The distance is calculated from a given point(x,y), for example:
If we have a point(0,0) and 2d array(sorted) {{3,0},{3,-1},{3,3},{5,0},{7,2}}. and the d = (square(11)), then the max distance element point in array from (0,0) that less than d is {3,-1}, and the function needs to return (1) because it is the next element in  the array.

Now the problem is the code outputting 3 instead of 1...!!!??  (note that I didn't use the function sqrt() in the code, instead I use d*d).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define X 0
#define Y 0

int square(int x);
int diff(int a, int b);
int find_distance(int points[][2], int n, int d);

int diff(int a, int b){
  int dis=square(a-X)+square(b-Y);
return dis;
}

int square(int x){
  return x*x;
}

int find_distance(int p[][2], int n, int d){
  int l=0, r=n-1, max=-1;
  while (l<r){
    int mid=(l+r)/2;
    if(diff(p[mid][0], p[mid][1])>= d*d)
        r=mid-1;
    else if (diff(p[mid][0],p[mid][1])<d*d){
        if (max<mid) 
            max=mid;
        l=mid+1;
    }

  }
  return max;
}

int main(){
  int p[5][2]={{3,0},{3,-1},{3,3},{5,0},{7,2}};
  int max=find_distance(p, 5, 11);
  printf("%d, %d", max, X);
}
```

Comment: In function `find_distance` what will happen when the `else if` is false? `l` and `r` remain unchanged. Should there be another `else`? Oh - no: the code is confusing because you make the same test twice, instead of a simple `else`.

Comment: @WeatherVane But I cover all that with the first if as well.... why they would remain unchanged?

Comment: I corrected the comment.

Comment: @WeatherVane do you know what is the problem here?

Comment: I thought so at first, but the best course is to step through with the debugger and find out what it is doing. My own preference in a binary search is to keep `r` out of range and stop when `(r - l <= 1)`

Comment: ... and then depending on the comparison, set `l = mid` or `r = mid`.

Comment: Hey You are messing up right .I would kindly suggest you to read the description twice "The code need to find the max element in the 2d array that has the distance less than <(square(d)).
".So it is at 4th index

Comment: @GaneshChowdharySadanala well, it's not surprising that WV 'messed up' given the question.  The first sentence intoduces two terms, 'distance' and '<(square(d))' that are not defined:(

Answer (score 0):

As per the question max element is at 4th index with 
(7)^2+(2)^2=53<121.

```
   int find_distance(int p[][2], int n, int d){
   int l=0, r=n-1, max=-1;
   while (l<=r)/*here l<=r because the largest 
      element is at 4th index*/{
    int mid=(l+r)/2;
     if(diff(p[mid][0], p[mid][1])>= d*d)
       r=mid-1;
     else if (diff(p[mid][0],p[mid][1])<d*d){
        if (max<mid) 
        max=mid;
     l=mid+1;
     }

   }
 return max;//4
}
```